# How to target a dash or hyphen in RegEx if used in a javascript .replace?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to target a dash or hyphen using RegEx. This seems to be impossible with how I'm using it though. The other answers I found online doesn't seem to match my scenario.

**Scenario:**

What should happen is if I click a button, this script will replace the specified numbers + letters. It's working fine, until now when I'm about to include a hyphen in the list.

Please take a look at the RegEx used below and here's the code:

```js
const mapper = new Map();
mapper.set("10th", "11th");
mapper.set("-", "Deleted");
mapper.set("63", "Deleted");
mapper.set("63-5", "Deleted");
mapper.set("121AA", "95");

function fixtext() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replace(
        /\b\d+(?:A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|AA|BB|CC|DD|EE|FF|GG|HH|II|JJ|KK|LL|MM|NN|OO|PP|QQ|RR|SS|TT|UU|VV|WW|XX|YY|ZZ|d|th|st|nd)?\b/g,
        m => mapper.has(m) ? mapper.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">(10th ed), Pretrial Proceedings sample 121AA and - and 63 63-5</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

For **63-5**, it should be changed as a whole and not as `Deleted-5`

I tried using several RegEx I saw online to escape hyphen or to match it. Here's some of them:
`[]-]`
`[a-zA-Z0-9!$* \t\r\n\-]`
`[-]`
`[abc-]`

None of these works for me or I cannot understand how to make it work this time.

I also would really like to shorten my RegEx but this is the problem as well. `[A-z]` or something like this doesn't work as well.

I'd really appreciate any help on how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const mapper = new Map();
mapper.set("10th", "11th");
mapper.set("-", "Deleted");
mapper.set("63", "Deleted");
mapper.set("63-5", "Deleted");
mapper.set("121AA", "95");

function fixtext() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if (elm) {
    elm.value = elm.value
      .replace(
        /\b\d+(?:[A-Z]|([A-Z])\1|d|th|st|nd)?(|\-\d)?\b/g,
        m => mapper.has(m) ? mapper.get(m) : m
      );
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">(10th ed), Pretrial Proceedings sample 121AA and - and 63 63-5</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

Comment: This is what I'm really looking for! Thank you so much for this! Just one question please, how can I also add a comma in the list? For example I want to target ```mapper.set("1, 3", "Random numbers");```?

Answer (score 2):

You can instead do it in a simpler way. You're only going to replace the keys in the map. So sort the keys by descending order of length and then replace each key with its value.

The descending sort by length is to make sure longer keys gets replaced first.

```js
const mapper = new Map();
mapper.set("10th", "11th");
mapper.set("-", "Deleted");
mapper.set("63", "Deleted");
mapper.set("63-5", "Deleted");
mapper.set("121AA", "95");
const keys = [...mapper.keys()].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);

function fixtext() {
  const elm = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  if (elm) {
    for (const key of keys) {
      elm.value = elm.value.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), mapper.get(key));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea1" rows="4" cols="50">(10th ed), Pretrial Proceedings sample 121AA and - and 63 63-5</textarea>

<button class="nbtngreen" onclick="fixtext()">Update</button>
```

If you don't want to replace within a word, you can use word boundaries like so

```
elm.value = elm.value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g'), mapper.get(key));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. However, if I do this, I will encounter problem where it changes a value even if it shouldn't. For example, **1=600***; and if I paste a **21** in textarea, it will change it to **2600** when it shouldn't. And that's what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to sound ungrateful sir, however, can you please teach me how to use my script and only add a RegEx for hyphen?

Comment: You can use word boundaries like https://regexr.com/5kenl